# How to get the latest text file from network folder

Tags: c#

I need to get the data from the latest text file from network folder and display it in the richtextbox.

This is my code:

```
Path = $@"\\sr-data\Groups\EG\Shares\PC\PG-14\SS\SystemLog";
string pattern = "*.txt";
DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Path);
            
FileInfo[] files = directoryInfo.GetFiles(pattern);
DateTime recentWrite = DateTime.MinValue;
FileInfo recentFile = null;

foreach (FileInfo file in files)
{
    if (file.LastWriteTime > recentWrite)
    {
        recentWrite = file.LastWriteTime;
        recentFile = file;
    }
}
           
richTextBox1.LoadFile(recentFile.ToString(), RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
```

This code is not working. It keeps displaying the error.

The error is

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not find file 'C:\Users\as\source\repos\SC\SC\bin\Debug\SystemLog_20201021-1204.txt'.'

How can i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LINQ instead of loop

```
using System.Linq;

FileInfo recentFile = directoryInfo.GetFiles(pattern).OrderByDescending(x => x.LastWriteTime).First();
```

Then use `recentFile.FullName` to get full file's path (make sure to check null before using **recentFile**).

Answer (score 1):

Try
`recentFile.FullName` instead of `recentFile.ToString()`

ToString() returns FileInfo.Name which is causing it to look for the file in the your app's directory.